# Why are my doctrine queries with inner joins returning multi-dimensional arrays?

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, multidimensional-array, doctrine, resultset

I am using Doctrine 1.2 under the Zend framework to run my database queries.  I have two tables that I query using inner join, like so:

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->from('My_Model_MaterialsFromDb g')
    ->innerJoin('t.My_Model_TeachingMaterials t');
    ->where('g.id= ?', $id)
$result = $q->fetchArray();
```

Basically, the first table (materialsFromDb) contains a list of all of the teaching materials that I use for a lesson.  The second one (teachingMaterials) has the details of the materials themselves.

When I run this query, here's what the result invariably looks like:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [activityId] => 1
        [materialId] => 2
        [My_Model_Materials] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2
                [title] => My Groovy Material
                [materialType] => Worksheet
                [description] => This is my groovy material. It looks really cool.
                [filename] => Groovy Material.doc
                [uploaderId] => 1
                [uploadDate] => 2012-02-16
            )

    )
)
```

Is there any way I can run a doctrine query to "flatten" this to a single array?  Is the result looking like this because both tables have a primary key called "id"? Having this multidimensional array as my result is a real pain to say the least.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

according to the Doctrine 1.2 docs, this is exaclty what's supposed to happen.

```
Doctrine hydration removes all duplicated data. It also performs many other things such as:

Custom indexing of result set elements
Value casting and preparation
Value assignment listening
Makes multi-dimensional array out of the two-dimensional result set array, the number of dimensions is equal to the number of nested joins
Now consider the DQL equivalent of the SQL query we used:

// test.php

// ...


 $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
        ->select('u.id, u.username, p.phonenumber')
        ->from('User u')
        ->leftJoin('u.Phonenumbers p');

    $results = $q->execute(array(), Doctrine_Core::HYDRATE_ARRAY);

    print_r($results);
The structure of this hydrated array would look like:

$ php test.php
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [username] =>
            [Phonenumbers] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [phonenumber] => 123 123
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [phonenumber] => 456 123
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 3
                            [phonenumber] => 123 777
                        )

                )

        )
    // ...
)
```

try...

```
$result = $q->execute(array(), Doctrine_Core::HYDRATE_NONE);
```

or...

```
$result = $q->execute(array(), Doctrine_Core::HYDRATE_SCALAR);
```

this one should return something like

```
$user = array(
    'u_username' => 'jwage',
    'u_password' => 'changeme',
    // ...
);
```